# Using WinSCP with SFTP server and two SSH tunnel hops

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, winscp

I'm on a Windows machine using PuTTY to ssh into my schools server. From there I need to `slogin -XY machine1` and then `slogin -XY machine2`.

Ideally, I'd like to use WinSCP to connect and transfer files. I know I can do this by using two copies of PuTTY, one to ssh into the server and create a proxy, and the second PuTTY to connect to the proxy and login to machine1 and create a second proxy. I can then use WinSCP to connect to the proxy server and login to machine2...

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

WinSCP has direct support for one hop.
See the [Tunnel page of its Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

---

For the [other hop (the first of the two)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_two), you can use [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) in *"local proxy command"* feature.

The configuration will look like:

- The first hop on the [Proxy page of Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_proxy):

  The *"Local proxy command"* needs to be set to:

  ```
  plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -nc %host:%port
  ```

  And of course, you need to have Plink installed (part of the [PuTTY package](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)).

  [image]

  For this to work, the authentication has to proceed seamlessly, without any prompt. So typically using [`-pw` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw) for a password authentication or Pageant for public key authentication. There are clones of Plink that support interactive authentication though. See *"Local proxy command with GUI authentication"* section of my answer to [How can I save SSH tunnel settings with multi-factor authentication in PuTTY or mRemoteNG?](https://superuser.com/q/1432414/213663)
- The second hop on the [Tunnel page of Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel):

  [image]
- And the final server goes to the [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel):

  [image]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use MobaXterm: it has a graphical sftp function like WinSCP, but it also allows you to go through your machine hops automatically. They call it "SSH bouncing".

You just have to
- download MobaXterm from here: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html
- Click on "New session" and choose "ssh"
- Specify your first machine name or IP address in the "SSH bouncing (connect through a gateway ssh server).

Comment: But that's for a **single** hop only. [WinSCP can do that too](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel). The question is about **two** hops. That does not seem to be possible with MobaXterm. While actually WinSCP can do it, as [my answer shows](https://superuser.com/q/477312/213663#1489111).

Answer (score 1):

Are machines 1 and 2 unix based? If so, couldn't you just use Unix scp? You wouldn't be able to use winscp to transfer files between two unix based systems anyway.

From source machine,

```
scp -rp user@hostname:destination_directory /path/to/files
```

You haven't made it clear exactly where from and where to you want to transfer the files.

Comment: yes machines 1 and 2 are unix based. I am wanting to transfer files from my windows pc to the machine2.

Comment: Well, you could copy the files into the server first on winscp and then 'scp -rp' to transfer them from the server to machine

Comment: @Jay WinSCP supports SCP, as does PuTTY (`pscp -scp`, all other SCP params should be the same)